# Why can't a variable store more than one command?

Tags: bash

I'm trying different things in bash, and found this behaviour that I can't understand.

```
CODE="pwd";$CODE
```

This code is running fine.

```
CODE="pwd;pwd";$CODE
```

But this is not working. (apparently ; is breaking it, same with &&)
Any ideas why ?

Comment: Generally speaking it's bad practice to store code in a variable. There is almost always a better way to solve whatever problem it is that you're addressing.

Comment: @roaima Oh I know it is bad practice, just wondering why the shell is behaving this way.

Answer (score 1):

Shell executes `$CODE` as one command. If you create a command named `pwd;pwd` in your path, that will get run. To run that `$CODE`, explicitly feed it to shell, so do:

```
CODE="pwd;pwd";sh -c "$CODE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Expansion of variables happens a lot later than parsing the command line. The value inside the variable `CODE` will expand at that time but it will not be re-parsed by the shell. Additionally, if the value inside `CODE` doesn't have any of the characters inside IFS the value is not split and the shell will try to execute the whole content of the variable as one command. Of couse, in your case, there is no executable file called `env;env` in the PATH and all that the shell could do is to report an error, that it can not find such file.

However, this will work (in bash):

```
CODE="pwd;pwd"; sh -s <<<"$CODE"
```

Please avoid using variables in uppercase, those are usually used as environment variables. Lets try to conform to that guideline.